# xcode - Button terminology - What is this button type called?

Tags: ios

I'm trying to create a iphone app that that simply references items by category. i.e. - clothing -> shirts ->.....etc

My question is this. I am trying to find the name/terminology of what a certain type of button is called. I would like to mimic the categories button that is used in the App Store (on the iphone). When the categories button is pressed, it does a slide to the right movement to the next screen, or vice versa if you choose to go back. I've tried to google the description of this "button" but must be using the wrong terminology. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance

Comment: For the german community there is a great Tutorial! https://bedifferently.wordpress.com/2011/11/09/uibutton-uibuttontype/

Answer (score 0):

The "categories" button in the app store is a button in a `UIToolbar`. This presents you with a `UINavigationController` which is the object that controls the sliding in and out of the various screens.

I think these terms are what you are looking for - there are lots of resources out there now you know what to search for.